# Running a function in Python in Parallel using multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, windows-10, python-multiprocessing

I have a python function

```
def noflux(j,i,cells,a,b,c,d):
```

that takes the arguments

```
j,i (integers)
cells (shape = (87,72), Type: ndarray),
a,b,c,d (shape = (87,72), Type: ndarray)
```

My laptop has 4 cores so as I understand it, the function should be able to be run 4 times at once with different arguments. The function doesn't currently return anything but just makes changes to the arguments.

I have tried to run some code using the mp.Process module but this doesn't work (code below):

```
p1 = mp.Process(target=noflux,args=[j,i,cells,rfu,lfu,ufu,dfu])
p2 = mp.Process(target=noflux,args=[j,i,cells,rfh,lfh,ufh,dfh])

p1.start()
p2.start()
            
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

I have also looked into the Pool and starmap modules but have not been able to get these to work either.
I think the problem has something to do with "pickle" but I'm not really sure what this is as I'm new to python as well as parallel processing!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to [multiprocessing doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), it seems that `args` should be tuple.

```py
p2 = mp.Process(target=noflux,args=(j,i,cells,rfh,lfh,ufh,dfh,))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When trying this I get a "BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe"... Since only tuples are accepted I might try to turn them back to numpy objects within the function

Comment: If what you want is that several processes modify the same objects, you should refer to [share state between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), since regular variables can't be shared by processes.

Comment: I'm not sure I want to modify the same objects across multiple processes, I just want to modify the arguments passed to the function and these arguments change for each process. I'll make sure to read through the documentation carefully though, thanks :))